# Endless import of matplotlib in Lambda Container: Matplotlib is building the font cache; this may take a moment

Tags: python, docker, matplotlib, lambda, containers

I am using the following Docker Image as a Lambda Container.
When I invoke the Container, it exceeds the time limit of 15 min because of the matplotlib import building the font cache. I tried all the tips provided to this issue on Stack Overflow but it is not working.
Does anybody know some ways to solve this problem? My matplotlib version is 3.5.1

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.7

COPY . /var/task/

RUN pip install -r /var/task/requirements.txt
#ENV MPLCONFIGDIR = /tmp
RUN rm -rf ~/.cache/matplotlib
RUN rm -rf /root/.cache/matplotlib
#RUN pip uninstall -y matplotlib

CMD ["my_handler.lambda_handler"]
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello! Did you find a solution? I have the same issue and cannot avoid importing matplotlib :(

Comment: My matplotlib version is 3.5.1 as well

Comment: For me this problem was solved when removing a second ```import pandas as pd``` statement from a ```helper_functions.py``` script.